# CXF Unmarshalling error: Unexpected Element

Tags: java, cxf

Application A provides the SOAP service endpoint and Application B is the consumer. Application A sends a response ProdDTO

```
class ProdDTO {
    private String a1;
    private String h1;
    private String t1;
}
```

The consumer is using the following plugin to generate sources from the WSDL

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>

<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>wsdl2022</wsdl>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdloptions>
```

The consumer has been using WSDL since 2022. The generated DTO looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "prodDTO", propOrder = { "a1","h1","t1" })
public class ProdDTO
{
    protected String a1;
    protected String h1;
    protected String t1;
}
```

Application A added fields to ProdDTO since then

```
private String c1;
private string s1;
```

and there was no issue from the consumer.

Application A added recently the below field to ProdDTO

```
private String z1;
```

Now the consumer throws error::

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"z1").
 Expected elements are <{}a1>,<{}h1>,<{}t1>
```

Why "z1" field raise an error but "c1" and "s1" did not? Does it have to do with propOrder? How do we resolve the issue? The consumer has some restrictions right now and is reluctant to change the code. So what can be done in Application A to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Which XML are you deserializing that triggers the exception? Please add it to the question.